# Spring JDBC can not connect to postgres database , but plain JDBC is able to connect

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-jdbc

I am trying to setup database connection using postgresql. I was using plain vanila JDBC , and was able to connect to database successfully.

But , when I am giving same connection parameters using `JdbcTemplate` , I am unable to connect.

Please have a look at my code and configurations :

```
<bean  name="dataSource" id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5342/testdbnew" /> 
    <property name="username" value="admin1" />
    <property name="password" value="admin1" />
</bean>    

<bean  id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean> 

<bean name="announcementNewsDAO" id="announcementNewsDAO" class="test.dao.AnnouncementNewsDAOImpl">
</bean>
```

and here is the way I am accessing through code :

First I am creating a class to implement `ApplicationContextAware` .Then , from that reference I am calling the `jdbcTemplate` object.

```
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

private static ApplicationContext context;

 public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
    return context;
}

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ac)
        throws BeansException {
    context = ac;
    System.out.println("Context initialized...");
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = (JdbcTemplate) context.getBean("jdbcTemplate");
    System.out.println("jdbcTemplate initialized..");

}
```

}

and

this is class of AnnouncementDAOImpl :

```
public class AnnouncementNewsDAOImpl implements AnnouncementNewsDAO {


/**
 * JDBCTemplate object for accessing database
 */
@Autowired
private  JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate ;


@Override
public void insertAnnouncementNews(AnnouncementNews news) {

    String insertQuery = "<db query for insert>";
    try {

        Object[] args = new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(news.getSlno()), news.getStakeholder_code(), news.getInfo_type(), news.getAnnouncement_news(),null,null};


        int result = jdbcTemplate.update(insertQuery, args);

        if(result!=0){
            System.out.println("Announcement news inserted for the serial number : "+news.getSlno());
        }else{
            System.err.println("Could not insert announcement news for the serial number : "+news.getSlno());
        }


    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        System.err.println("Exception occurred while parsing date : "+pe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

and I am getting error :

> org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:628)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:907)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:968)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:978)
>       at Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:207)

Comment: Your connection is closed the server refused the connection, you should check your firewall settings.

Comment: If it's Windows, disable your firewall. Also, I hope the configuration details are correct.

Comment: This question should probably be closed, since it was just a simple typo that was the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typo in the port?

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5342/iitkgpdbnew" />
```

The default PostgreSQL port is 5432. Unless you changed it to 5342 of course :)